# How do I let the Angular-bootstrap popover shows the dictionary value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular-bootstrap.  I used ng-repeat to bind an array of objects. (please see the code below).

When I popped-over the checkbox, I would like to show the dictionary value, instead of the key.  Any idea for how to do that? Thank you for your help in advance!

PS: I understand, that I can also set the dictionary value as part of object in the list (such as { Id: 5, checked: true, Name:'C#' }), but please forgive me that  I have no control for the data returns from the source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html ng-app="mlApp">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('mlApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
            .controller('mlCtrl', [function () {
                var self = this;
                self.lists = [{ Id: 5, checked: true }, { Id: 6, checked: false }, { Id: 8, checked: true }, { Id: 9, checked: true }, { Id: 11, checked: false}];

                // implement a dictionary here for the pop over to call
                self.dictList = [{ key: 5, value: 'C#' }, { key: 6, value: 'Javascript' }, { key: 8, value: 'Angular' }, { key: 9, value: 'T-SQL' }, { key: 11, value: 'Linq'}];


            } ]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div ng-controller="mlCtrl as mCtrl">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="m in mCtrl.lists"><input type="checkbox" popover="{{ mCtrl.dictList[$index].value }}" popover-trigger="mouseenter"  ng-model="m.checked" ng-checked="m.checked" />{{m.Id}}</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does popover="{{ mCtrl.dictList[m.Id].value }}" not work?

Comment: {{ mCtrl.dictList[m.Id].value }} doesn't show anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The dictionary list format is incorrect. It should change to

```
self.dicList = {'key':'value', 'key2':'value'};
```

ie

```
self.dictList = { '6': 'Javascript', '8': 'Angular', '9': 'T-SQL', '11': 'Linq', '5': 'C#' };
```

please see below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html ng-app="mlApp">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('mlApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
            .controller('mlCtrl', [function () {
                var self = this;
                self.lists = [{ 'Id': '5', 'checked': true }, { 'Id': '6', 'checked': false }, { 'Id': '8', 'checked': 'true' }, { 'Id': '9', 'checked': 'true' }, { 'Id': '11', 'checked': 'false'}];

                // implement a dictionary here for the pop over to call

                self.dictList = { '6': 'Javascript', '8': 'Angular', '9': 'T-SQL', '11': 'Linq', '5': 'C#' };

            } ]);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div style="margin-left:100px; margin-top:100px" ng-controller="mlCtrl as mCtrl">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="m in mCtrl.lists">
            <input type="checkbox" popover="{{ mCtrl.dictList[m.Id] }}" popover-trigger="mouseenter"  ng-model="m.checked" ng-checked="m.checked" /> {{ m.Id }}
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is m.Id is not the index of the item, it's its property

if this is what you really want to achieve I would say

```
{{ mCtrl.dictList[$index] }}
```

or make a scope function which searches the the dict item from the dictList based on the key

Comment: thank you. however, if I switch the order of dictionary objects, the $index won't work correctly...

Comment: that is right, so you might want to use a get function

Comment: {{ mCtrl.dictList[$index].value }} will get the value.... let me  see if I can figure it out how to use function....thanks

Comment: if you use underscore, it's quite simple: 

self.getDict = function getDict(key) {
  return _.findWhere(self.dictList, {id: key});
}

popover="{{ mCtrl.getDict(m.Id).value }}"